# Dynamically added script element with its src attribute doesn't load the js file in src

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror

I am using the CodeMirror editor. And it has an option which allows to change the mode (language). I created a code to load the .js file which corresponds to the language. See the code below. Everything works fine. the script element with its src attribute is added to head, but the codemirror editor doesn't load the language, because the script element is written in head, but it is probably not loaded.

The python highlighting js script which is written in the html file is loading correctly. Only the dynamically loaded js files aren't working with codemirror.

Please help me, I can't fix this.

```js
languageselect.addEventListener("change",function(){
        language =  languageselect.value ;
        let header = document.head;
        let script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "codemirror/mode/" + language + "/" + language + ".js";
        header.appendChild(script);
        editor.setOption("mode",language);
      });
```

```html
<script src="codemirror/mode/python/python.js"></script>

<!--The python highlighting js script which is written in the html file is loading correctly. Only the dynamically loaded js file aren't working with codemirror.-->
```

Comment: What errors show up in the console?

Comment: Are you familiar with using dev tools? Check the Network pane and verify the script is loading at all.

Comment: @RandyCasburn no errors. Just not loading in the browser

Comment: @CodeSpent I am using the dev tools to take a look at the code. I can open and read perfectly the dynamically added js file.

Comment: next question: is the editor running in an iFrame?

Comment: @RandyCasburn No I simply open the html file in the browser

Comment: I think we'd need more data to troubleshoot, then. Get us some code we can verify in a fiddle.

Comment: @CodeSpent you can't. Codemirror has to be downloaded

Comment: That's not important, we can use other sources since we don't care about anything other than the script loading. With what you provided currently, there's nothing we can do but ask you questions which isn't efficient.

Comment: The code you provide should: Allow us to initiate the change event, and let us append to the header.

Comment: I found how to fix that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix that. When creating the script element's attributes, create a onload attribute, which will run a function to change the CodeMirror editor's mode :

```js
      languageselect.addEventListener("change",function(){
        language =  languageselect.value ;
        src = "codemirror/mode/" + language + "/" + language + ".js";
        let header = document.head;
        
        let script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.onload = change_language;
        header.appendChild(script);
      
      });

      function change_language(){
        language =  languageselect.value;
        editor.setOption("mode",language);
      };
```